# Recover files from RPi after doing chmod 777 / -R?

Tags: data-transfer, recovery

I know, I'm an idiot, I have no backups, let's move forward. Is there any way I can get the files off the SD card? I did `sudo chmod 777 / -R` and can no longer connect to the device over SSH or SFTP.

Comment: Have you tried mounting the sd card on another system?

Answer (score 1):

Oh Man, what a screw up.Do you have any other access to the device?

In all honesty I would mount drive on another computer, copy important files and reinstall.

Unfortunately Many things in linux are picky about permissions, SSH is probably among the pickiest.

---

To restore only SSH/SFTP, you can start by correcting permissions for private and public keys under the sshd directory.

```
chmod -R 644 /etc/ssh
chmod 600 /etc/ssh/*_key
```

That is, folder, configs and public keys get set to `644` and private keys to `600`

If you are using key authentication, the same must be done for user config and key files under `$HOME/.ssh/`

---

Otherwise, you may attempt to reinstall all packages using dpkg

This is taken from a [unix.se answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/79165/39841). Note just like the author of that answer, I did not test this sequence.

```
dpkg --get-selections > selections
sudo dpkg --clear-selections
sudo dpkg --set-selections < selections
sudo apt-get --reinstall dselect-upgrade
```